# Evaluate$\int_{\Gamma} \frac{e^{e^{iz}}}{z}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $f(z)=\frac{e^{e^{iz}}}{z}$ and let $\Gamma$ be the semicircle of radius $R$ in the upper half plane. Evaluate $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_\Gamma f(z)dz$.

I managed to show that
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\left|\int_\Gamma f(z)dz\right|\leq\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^\pi e^{e^{-R\sin(\theta)}\cos(R\cos(\theta))}d\theta=\pi.$$
Is it possible that the integral goes to 0 in the limit and if so, how would you show that?

Comment: Haven't checked your work yet, but by any chance, did this contour integral come from trying to evaluate a real improper integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it is possible to show that the integral converges to $i\pi$:

$$ \int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{e^{e^{iz}}}{z} \, \mathrm{d}z
= i \int_{0}^{\pi} \exp( e^{-R\sin\theta + iR\cos\theta}) \, \mathrm{d}\theta
\quad \xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{\text{DCT}} \quad
i \int_{0}^{\pi} \exp(0) \, \mathrm{d}\theta
= i\pi. $$

As a corollary, we can verify that

$$ \mathrm{PV}\! \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{e^{ix}}}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= (e - 1)\pi i. $$

(This can also be proved by a purely real-analytic method, though.)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did end up trying DCT which worked out. I'm too used to those Gamma integrals going to 0... DCT was also required when considering the integral of radius epsilon around zero to integrate the above function, which was what I was trying to do initially.